# Visual Studio Extensibility Essentials 2019: How to get the type of the selected item?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to create a VS extension, using Visual Studio Extensibility Essentials 2019. The extension needs to get the type of the selected item in a Visual Studio code file. I am able to get the text that was selected, but I would like to get the type of the selected item, so that I can use reflection to display more information.

```
[Command(PackageIds.MyCommand)]
internal sealed class MyCommand : BaseCommand<MyCommand>
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(OleMenuCmdEventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = await VS.Documents.GetActiveDocumentViewAsync();
        var span = doc.TextView.Selection.SelectedSpans.FirstOrDefault();
        var text = span.GetText();
        await VS.MessageBox.ShowWarningAsync("MyCommand", text);
    }
}
```

Any ideas, code samples, etc would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You should do it with regex, parse class and properties and it's types.
check the regex code is true ,perhaps fails.

```
var code = doc.ReadAllText();

var match = Regex.Match(code, "\\s*(static)?\\s*(public|private)\\s*\\w+\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(\\(\\s*\\w*(,?\\s*\\w+)*\\))?");

Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
```

Comment: The question is asking how to get the System.Type, I don't think they're having issue getting the name of the Type (seemingly the user's selected text).

Comment: there is no way to take the type  of object because its another project.  you must import  dll files or  you can read .cs file of the model and read it's properties via regex and also read all model files recursively into a dictionary to read files if you need dependency . i did it this way too